# Wordpress проблема с пагинацией

Tags: php, wordpress

Возникла проблема с навигацией на сайте. Ее попросту нету. И пробовал подключать свою, и с помощью плагинов и без, ни в какую. Любые изменения в нужном месте отображаются, а вот навигация нет. Сайт делал не я. Спасибо.

***Обновление***

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
 <!-- #blocks-wrapper-->
<div id="blocks-wrapper" class="clearfix">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();  ?>    
<!-- /blocks Left-->
    <div id="blocks-left" <?php post_class('eleven columns');?>>        
    <!-- .post-content-->
    <div class="post-content">   
    <!--/.post-outer -->
        <div class="post-outer clearfix">
            <!--.post-title-->
              <div class="post-title"><h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1></div>
              <!--/.post-title-->
         <!-- .post_content -->
          <div class = 'post_content entry-content'>
            <div>
            </div>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>                
         </div> 
         <!-- /.post_content -->
                <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>

                <div class='clear'></div>
        </div>
    <!--/.post-outer -->

    </div>
    <!-- post-content-->


<?php comments_template(); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <!-- /blocks Left -or -right -->            
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Код страницы на которой нужна навигация, а пытался ее реализовать как плагинами всяческими так и без них. После установки плагина, он мне говорит, вызвать функцию навигации на нужной странице, но никаких изменений.
     ***Обновление***

```
var_damp($wp_query->max_num_pages);
```

результат

```
int(0)
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: вы о пагинации?

Comment: Да, о пагинации.

Comment: Опишите подробнее, как пытались подключить, приведите пример кода страницы, на которой не работает навигация

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете функцию `wp_link_pages()`, которая нужна для многостраничных постов (если пост нужно разбить на несколько страниц), а не для навигации по сайту. Если вам необходима классическая "пагинация", используйте функцию `wp_list_pages()` ([документация](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/)). Обратите также внимание, что она, в отличие от `wp_link_pages()`, используется вне цикла `while(have_posts())`

Comment: wp_link_pages() до меня еще вызвана была в том месте, но она ничего не дает, у меня есть какое то количество записей, и мне нужно сделать постраничную навигацию с определенным количеством записей на страницу.

Comment: повторюсь: `wp_link_pages()` вам **не нужна**. Вам нужно использовать функцию `wp_list_pages()`. Прочтите мой ответ внимательней, названия функций схожи, но работа принципиальным образом отличается. Кроме того, проверьте, что в настройках сайта (your_site_name.com/wp-admin/options-reading.php) установлено правильное ограничение по числу записей на одну страницу (пункт "На страницах блога отображать не более")

Comment: А я и не говорю что мне нужна wp_link_pages() и все эти настройки у меня стоят в админке, функция wp_list_pages() выводит просто список всех страниц а не навигацию.

Comment: При том выводит список страниц с другим контентом.